# Javascript Youtube grabbing XML data, want to append to a div, not working in all versions of IE

Tags: javascript, xml, json, youtube, appendchild

Here is the example:
http://www.jackthe7th.com/jts_test.php

Whats happening is I'm grabbing the XML data using JSON for each video in the playlist, and then trying to append that data to the div.  It works without even having to append the data to the div in every browser except IE, and this includes all versions of IE.  In IE, it does not append anything, and it all appears at the top of the page.  I have tried hundreds of combinations over days to try and figure this out, and no matter what it does not budge in IE.  I know this one is kind of complicated, but if anyone can help it would be great!

All the code is html or javascript, and is too long to post here, so just inspect the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `document.getElementsByName('vid_thumb_title')` from IEs console returns an array of length zero [per the w3c spec name is not a valid attribute on a div element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-DIV) and IEs javascript engine has always been super picky about only checking for a name on elements where name is a valid attribute.

Comment: Yes, thankyou for that.  I solved it by using jQuery instead, creating an array with all IDs of a certain name, I didn't want to, but it works in all browsers now (except for a different bug with IE7 but thats besides the point)